# For loop with EqCase, StrLeft is not working

Tags: macros, xstring

This is my document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}

    \begin{document}
    
    \makeatletter
    \newcommand{\test}[1]%
    {%
        \@for\@tag:=#1\do%
        {%
            \IfEqCase{\StrLeft{\@tag}{1}}%
            {%
                {a}{First letter is a}%
                {b}{First letter is b}%
            }%
        }%
    }
    
    \test{aa,ab}
    \makeatother
    
\end{document}
```

When I compile it, it'll produce this:

[image]

I honestly have no idea what's going on. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\StrLeft` is not expandable since it has an optional argument for a macro to which the `\StrLeft` content is stored at the end. A possible solution is to remove the `\StrLeft` from the `\IfEqCase` command and use this optional argument, storing to, say, `\foostring` and using `\foostring` in the `\IfEqCase` command.

The empty line almost at the end in the code of `\testit` is on purpose.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\testit}[1]{%
  \@for\@tag:=#1\do%
  {%
    \StrLeft{\@tag}{1}[\foostring]
    \IfEqCase{\foostring}%
    {%
      {a}{First letter is a}%
      {b}{First letter is b}%
    }%

  }%
}

\testit{aa,ab,ba}
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can “reuse” `\@tag` instead of `\foostring`.

Answer (score 3):

You may enjoy a different way to solve your problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{m}
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \str_case_e:nnF { \tl_head:n { ##1 } }
     {
      {a}{First~letter~is~a}
      {b}{First~letter~is~b}
     }
     {First~letter~is~neither~a~nor~b}
    \par
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\test{aa,ab , bc, xy}

\end{document}
```

The `\clist_map_inline:nn` function is the counterpart of `\@for`, but has some advantages over it:

- it ignores leading and trailing spaces;
- it doesn't require a dummy control sequence, as the current item is denoted by `#1` (here `##1` because we're calling it in the body of a definition).

The function `\str_case_e:nnF` is the counterpart of `\IfEqCase`; with `\tl_head:n { ##1 }` we isolate the first token in the current item of the comma separated list (that is, it does the job of `\StrLeft`).

[image]

In a real world example, it could be possible to avoid `~` and use spaces, but more information about how you plan to use the functions is necessary.

Comment: Does not work as is with utf8-inputenc chars.

Comment: @jfbu Never claimed it does. Strings are not arbitrary text.

Answer (score 0):

A `listofitems` approach.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\newcommand\test[1]{%
  \setsepchar{,}%
  \readlist*\testlist{#1}%
  \foreachitem\i\in\testlist{\expandafter\testfirst\i\testlistend}
}
\def\testfirst#1#2\testlistend{First letter is #1.\par}
\begin{document}
\test{aa,ab,ba}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is another method. I am using `xinttools`'s `\xintFor`  for handling the comma separated list and removing automatically spaces in this process, plus a bit of low-level TeX.

I have added support for utf8-encoded characters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xinttools}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    

\newcommand{\test}[1]{\xintFor ##1 in {#1}\do
 {(##1)
  \iftextstartswith{##1}{a}\xintdothis{First letter is a}\fi
  \iftextstartswith{##1}{b}\xintdothis{First letter is b}\fi
  \iftextstartswith{##1}{à}\xintdothis{First letter is à}\fi
  \iftextstartswith{##1}{é}\xintdothis{First letter is é}\fi
  \xintorthat{First letter is neither a nor b nor à nor é}\par
 }%
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\iftextstartswith}[2]{%
  \def\iftextstartswith@aux ##1#2##2\@@nil{\if\relax\detokenize{##1}\relax}%
  \iftextstartswith@aux #1\@nil#2\@@nil
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\test{aa,ab , bc, xy , éa , àu ,ééé}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Notice that the `\iftextstartswith{foo}{bar}` can be used with ̀bar` being multiple characters. For example in the above we could have used `\iftextstartswith{##1}{éé}`.